# What is the difference between static and dynamic testing?

Tags: test-automation-framework

Describe static and dynamic testing briefly…

Answer (score 2):

https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso-iec-ieee:29119:-1:ed-1:v1:en

there are many online sources available the common definition is

> **dynamic testing:**
>
> testing that requires the execution of the test item,
>
> **static testing**
>
> testing in which a test item is examined against a set of quality or
> other criteria without code being executed

In simple terms, **static testing** is when you try to find issues without actually compiling the code.
Eg : static analysis in which you check for invalid syntax, code smells, etc

Code reviews, document reviews, etc also are static testing as they don't execute any code

WHile dynamic test are test that conducted by compilling and running the code, in this type of testing you get actuall runtime bugs.

Eg UI tests, API tests , etc where you deploy the actual service  be fore you could tesst it

Answer (score 0):

Usually *static testing* refers to the risk evaluation that doesn't involve exploring the product in action. For software products, it may include code review (which may include automated style checking), specification reviews, etc.

*Dynamic testing* usually refers to risk evaluation through the exploration of the product in action. For software products, it usually includes running the code itself in certain situations and evaluating its execution.